# Why do we use two filters?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs6

Why do we use two filters in code below instead one?

```
 fromEvent<MouseEvent>(this.mapElement, "click")
    .pipe(
        filter(e => !this.props.disableEvents),
        filter(_ => !this.mouseState.moved && mouseDownInMap)
    )
    .subscribe(e => {});
```

Why not:

```
fromEvent<MouseEvent>(this.mapElement, "click")
    .pipe(filter( e => !this.props.disableEvents && !this.mouseState.moved && mouseDownInMap))
    .subscribe(e => {});
```

Also, why we need `.pipe()` if it works without pipe too?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You *can* combine them into a single `filter`.

But for the sake of code maintenance it's often easier to read two separate filter functions, especially if they're conceptually unrelated - and to avoid horizontal scrolling.

Another reason is that the filter functions themselves may be defined elsewhere, in which case you'll have to use separate `filter` calls anyway:

e.g.

```
function whenEventsAreEnabled( e ) {
    return !this.props.disableEvents;
}

function whenMouseIsInMap( e ) {
    !this.mouseState.moved && mouseDownInMap
}

fromEvent<MouseEvent>(this.mapElement, "click")
    .pipe(
        filter( whenEventsAreEnabled ),
        filter( whenMouseIsInMap )
    )
    .subscribe(e => {});
```

> Also, why we need `.pipe()` if it works without `pipe` too?

You **do** need `pipe`. You can only get-away without using `pipe` if you're using RxJS in [backwards compatibility mode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs-compat). [Modern RxJS always requires `pipe()` to create a pipeline for the observable's emitted values/objects](https://blog.hackages.io/rxjs-5-5-piping-all-the-things-9d469d1b3f44).

Comment: @OPV  If you have 2 questions, it's usually best in SO to ask 2 questions.

Comment: Could you explain whats role of pipe in my case?

Comment: @OPV You need to use `pipe` to use any of the Pipable Operators. This is fully documented in RxJS's website, so I won't waste my time repeating information you can **easily find** here: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/operators

Answer (score 1):

> Also, why we need .pipe() if it works without pipe too?

You don't need it but it improves readibility when several operators are going to act. From [docs](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/operators):

> Pipeable operators are functions, so they could be used like ordinary
>   functions: op()(obs) — but in practice, there tend to be many of them
>   convolved together, and quickly become unreadable:
>   op4()(op3()(op2()(op1()(obs)))). For that reason, Observables have a
>   method called .pipe() that accomplishes the same thing while being
>   much easier to read:

```
obs.pipe(
  op1(),
  op2(),
  op3(),
  op3(),
)
```